# How to automatically compile client side CoffeeScript files with Node.js / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

As the title says I'm trying to automatically compile the public static coffeescript files on page load, rather than having to compile them myself and use the .js files, how might I achieve this, I'm trying to maintain a full CoffeeScript stack, this is the only thing I'm having trouble figuring out.

tl;dr: Read the title of the post.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. Two of the easiest that I know of:

1. Use the [connect-assets](https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets) module. The idea behind this is that you have an `/assets` folder in the root, and you instantiate it with `express.static`, as you normally would with your `/public` folder. In there, you have two more folders: `/js` and `/css`. Your CoffeeScript goes in your `/js` folder. Then, from within your view template, just call `js('yourfile')`. It's a wonderfully simple module, but isn't the most advocated asset pipeline.
2. Use [asset-rack](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack). While not as simple to grasp as connect-assets, it's very flexible and is easy to extend. It would be the closest comparator to Rails' asset pipeline and is used by most of the popular JS frameworks (like Sails.js).

However, I would *really* advise that you refrain from on-the-fly compilation of assets, as it can really drain server performance.

It would be way better to compile on file save using a build system - CoffeeScript ships with Cake, so you can define a watch/compile/build/concatenate step right in your Cakefile and all it would take for you to compile on file save is to type `$ cake watch` in to the terminal before you change any code.

Alternatively you could write code, then `$ cake build`. Whichever you prefer. I might also add that [cake-flour](http://ricardo.cc/cake-flour/) takes *all* of the pain out of writing Cake tasks.

Answer (score 2):

```
coffee --watch --compile .
```

watches for files changes in `.` and compiles them as they change. Since you are using expressjs I think you would also like to restart the server as soon as a recompile happens:

```
coffee --compile --watch . &; nodemon server.js
```

which uses https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have access to compiled CoffeeScript files over HTTP, you could also give [connect-coffee-script](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-connect-coffee-script) middleware a try. It has worked quite well for me.

It has the advantage over using `coffee --watch --compile` that you don't need to have a separate program running.